# Matplotlib Agg Rendering Complexity Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to print a 600 dpi graph using Python matplotlib. However Python plotted 2 out of 8 graphs, and output the error:

```
OverflowError: Agg rendering complexity exceeded. Consider downsampling or decimating your data.
```

I am plotting a huge chunk of data (7,500,000 data per column) so I guess either that would be some overloading problem or that I need to set a large cell_block_limit.

I tried searching for the solutions for changing a cell_block_limit on Google but to no avail. What would be a good approach?

The code as follows:-

```
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter

        majorLocator   = MultipleLocator(200)
        majorFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%d')
        minorLocator   = MultipleLocator(20)

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
        ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
        ax.xaxis.grid(True,which='minor')
        ax.yaxis.grid(True)
        plt.plot(timemat,fildata)
        plt.xlabel(plotxlabel,fontsize=14)
        plt.ylabel(plotylabel,fontsize=14)      
        plt.title(plottitle,fontsize=16)
        fig.savefig(plotsavetitle,dpi=600)
```

Comment: It's a lot of data, considering a 1600x1200 would have 'only' 1,920,000 _pixels_ in there.  what kind of plot are you trying to make?  If it's a histogram you could bin them, a line could be subsampled ..

Comment: it's data from accelerometer sampled at 1500 Hz to capture high frequency shock. I am trying to make the simple Voltage (V) vs Time plot. So first I generate the similar amount of data for a time array, and plot the signal against the time.

Yes it's huge but in the future I am sure it will get even enormous since we're doing a 2 hours to 4 hours experiment. Please do tell me how to subsample a line...thank you so much!

Comment: use a slice on the inputs (on both axes).  for example, to select every 10th element of an array `x` you would use `x[::10]`

Comment: However, is there any way to plot the data without decimating any of them?

Comment: split it into separate plots.  you can't get that much information into an image unless it was really wide..

however, given what you said about high frequency shock, perhaps what would help you more would probably be looking at the high frequency part of the spectrum (FFT) rather than the time domain.

Comment: Hmmmmmm...I guess there is no other way then. =(
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to @Lennart's point that there's no need for the full resolution, you might also consider a plot similar to the following.

Calculating the max/mean/min of a "chunked" version is very simple and efficient if you use a 2D view of the original array and the `axis` keyword arg to `x.min()`, `x.max()`, etc.

Even with the filtering, plotting this is much faster than plotting the full array.

(Note: to plot this many points, you'll have to tune down the noise level a bit. Otherwise you'll get the `OverflowError` you mentioned. If you want to compare plotting the "full" dataset, change the `y += 0.3 * y.max() np.random...` line to more like `0.1` or remove it completely.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1977)

# Generate some very noisy but interesting data...
num = 1e7
x = np.linspace(0, 10, num)
y = np.random.random(num) - 0.5
y.cumsum(out=y) 
y += 0.3 * y.max() * np.random.random(num)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Wrap the array into a 2D array of chunks, truncating the last chunk if 
# chunksize isn't an even divisor of the total size.
# (This part won't use _any_ additional memory)
chunksize = 10000
numchunks = y.size // chunksize 
ychunks = y[:chunksize*numchunks].reshape((-1, chunksize))
xchunks = x[:chunksize*numchunks].reshape((-1, chunksize))

# Calculate the max, min, and means of chunksize-element chunks...
max_env = ychunks.max(axis=1)
min_env = ychunks.min(axis=1)
ycenters = ychunks.mean(axis=1)
xcenters = xchunks.mean(axis=1)

# Now plot the bounds and the mean...
ax.fill_between(xcenters, min_env, max_env, color='gray', 
                edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(xcenters, ycenters)

fig.savefig('temp.png', dpi=600)
```

[image]

Comment: SUPERB! Extremely informative and innovative way to look at the data! +++

Answer (score 3):

With 600dpi you would have to make the plot 13 meters wide to plot that data without decimating it. :-)

I would suggest chunking the data into pieces a couple of hundred or maybe even a thousand samples long, and extracting the maximum value out of that.

Something like this:

```
def chunkmax(data, chunk_size):
    source = iter(data)
    chunk = []
    while True:
        for i in range(chunk_size):
            chunk.append(next(source))

        yield max(chunk)
```

This would then, with a chunk_size of 1000 give you 7500 points to plot, where you then easily can see where in the data the shock comes. (Unless the data is so noisy you would have to average it to see if there is a chock or not. But that's also easily fixable).

Comment: thank you! seems like there is really no other way to plot a high dpi plot.

Comment: FYI: While it's an excellent suggestion, the actual code above is very inefficient for numpy arrays. You'd be better off doing something like `chunks = data.reshape((-1, chunk_size)); max_filtered = chunks.max(axis=1)`.  (Assuming the simple case where the chunk size is an even divisor of the total size... A generalized example is just an extra line or two, though.)

Comment: @JoeKington: Oh, he uses numpy? I didn't get that. Is really iterating over a numpy array innefficient? Oh well.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - Well, if he's storing >1e7 floats (8 columns of 2e6), I'm assuming he's using numpy (Otherwise he'd run into memory problems).  Matplotlib will convert it to a numpy array regardless.  Iterating through a numpy array is inefficient compared to iterating through a list, at any rate. The main reason is for memory efficiency.  The overhead in using a list to store large arrays of floats becomes very apparent at that size. `numpy` uses 1/4 as much memory as a list to store a large array of floats/ints/etc.

Comment: Yes I am using numpy to process the large chunk of data. In fact I did FFT and filtering with that size of data as well. Thanks @JoeKington for pointing out the memory problem. Enlightening solution too!

Comment: @JoeKington: Well, to plot them you don't need to store them. :-) The above function intentionally works with generators so you don't have to load the data into memory all at once. (But other parts might require that, of course).